# How to change title of google search list title

Tags: reactjs, meta-tags, meta-title

In this image you can see the result of codevaly it's show with my web title but i changed the title of my website to "codevaly" but still it return "my web", please help me to fix it

[Click To View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPa3T.png)

It is my html file of react js project
[Click To View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM4rt.png)

Now, Please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, insert your code and your problem in text. Pictures are frowned upon on Stackoverflow. Have you changed the title recently? If so, you might just need to wait for a google crawler to visit your page again.

More info can be found in the  [google search docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/title-link). Some other thing could improve the title, such as including an H1 element on your page that repeats the name.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your title and description both are not updated.

There are two possibilities for this

1. You have not deployed the recent code in production.
2. If not the first case then wait for google to crawl through your page.

Try checking with this `site:Your site URL`  to list out all the links in your web app.

Thanks.